# Why I cannot modify a UIScrollview leading edge programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm fairly new to iOS app development. I'm trying to make an iOS app which will have an horizontal scroll view with labels added as subviews which exhibit a snapping behaviour. I'm using UIKit and auto layouts (Swift 5, Xcode 12.01) for a programmatically build UI. I have three labels to be added to the scroll view, one is centred, one is offset 500 pt from the scrollview centre (right) and one is at -500 from the centre (left)

When I try to set the scrollview trailing anchor referring to the label on the right I have no problems. However, when I try to set the leading edge referring to the label on the left (leading edge), I encounter the error: **[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.**

Am I missing something?
I attach my code below:

```
// Create scroll view on top of bottom view
func createScrollView() -> UIScrollView {
    
    let myScrollView = UIScrollView()
    myScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    myScrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    view.addSubview(myScrollView)
    // Constraints
    myScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    myScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.firstBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
    myScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    
    // Add some elements to the view
    let label1 = UILabel()
    let label2 = UILabel()
    let label3 = UILabel()
    label1.text = "EV 0."
    label1.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label2.text = "ISO"
    label2.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label3.text = "SNAP"
    label3.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // Add labels to scroll view
    myScrollView.addSubview(label1)
    myScrollView.addSubview(label2)
    myScrollView.addSubview(label3)
    // Add constraint
    label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label3.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: -300).isActive = true
    label2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
    label3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    
    
    // Add last constraint in the scroll view
    myScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.leadingAnchor, constant: -500).isActive = true
    myScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.trailingAnchor, constant: 500).isActive = true
    return myScrollView
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do... Do you want to add a scroll view the width of `view`, with 3 labels spaced 300-pts apart, and start with the center label centered horizontally in the scroll view?

Comment: You have conflicting constraints.  You are trying to set the label1 to be -300 off of the scrollView's centerX, but also setting the scrollView's leading edge to be -500 from the label1's leading edge, and 0 from the self.view's leading edge.

Comment: @clawesome: basically I'm trying to override the first set of contraints (relative self.view's) to add dynamically labels to the scroll view and then adjust its size. Is there a reason why this works on the right? Basically, I thought it should be the same procedure but with negative offsets on the left. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DonMag: I would like to start with a scroll view with the width of `view`, then add labels, starting from center. As I wrote my logic works on the right, but I can never have my scroll view to scroll leftwards more than `view.leadingAnchor`

Comment: Can you give an overview of how you want the labels and scroll view to be to be laid out?

Comment: @Salvo89 - still confusing. Edit your question, and try to clearly describe what your goal is. Are you trying to create 3 "pages" in your scroll view? With each "page" having a label centered in it?